# Out of memory just on s4 while using Bitmap

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I have a lot of "out of memory" reports in an application from Galaxy S4 users.

The app is working with Bitmap . It has a graphical UI. It works good on all devices but on S4 it crashes.

Do you know if we need any special memory management for S4?

Comment: Has anyone tried on a Nexus 5? Are you scaling the bitmap(s) to screen size? The S4 has a pretty nice screen - anything scaled to screen size will use a lot more memory on that device than on some others.

Comment: I am using some various bitmaps on a rotator, not scaled to the whole screen. Anytime I start the activity, some part of the memory are lost.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t believe that S4 introduces something out of the ordinary with Memory management or Images. I guess looking at the memory usage of the app will be helpful.. Follow this guide to look at possible leaks and memory consumption of your app.

http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html

Since you said that you deal with images in your apps... In my apps I have had memory problems with bitmaps. A good tip is to use LRUCache to cache and manage bitmaps. Follow the link below to understand LruCache.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this, you need to understand how images use memory.

Imagine an image, 800x800 pixels.  Without any scaling, this will require approximately 2.5MB of memory.  Width x height x 4 bytes.

All loaded images are stored on the heap which is limited in size (there are many discussions on here about heap size).

Now load that image into an `ImageView` which is displayed on a 1024x768 screen, the size of the ImageView being 800x800 - the same size as the image.  You are using DIP as recommended so that your UI scales.

Your 1024x768 display has 786,432 pixels.  The S4 has 1920x1080 = 2,073,600 pixels.  Approximately 2.6 times as many as the 1024x768 device.

If you do not do anything to scale that image and you do not use the density and resolution "bucket" resource folders, then that same image now needs 2.5x2.6MB = 6.6MB.

> The key point is that unless you control it, your image will use
>   different amounts of heap memory (which is limited, it doesn't matter
>   how much RAM the device has) on different devices.

I suspect that your app would have problems on Nexus devices too.

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html